# How would I set a key delay between each sent character in AutoHotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to add a delay between sent characters with something like this:

```
^`::SetKeyDelay,100 Send 67890
```

I think this code works:

```
^`::
SetKeyDelay, 100
Send 67890
```

The goal is to get that code into one line.

Comment: Why get it into one line? AHK uses newlines as command separators

Comment: I guess because I have one autohotkey script that executes a bunch of stuff. it's easier to manage in one line.

Comment: It's not easier to manage

Answer (score 5):

Autohotkey doesn't support multiple commands per line (semicolons denote line comments). The documentation itself states

> Each script is a plain text file containing **lines** to be executed by the program (AutoHotkey.exe).

You could set the key delay globally (then each hotkey action is single-line):

```
SetKeyDelay, 100

;...

^`::Send 67890
```

Alternatively you could use a subroutine or a function:

```
type(speed, str){
  SetKeyDelay, %speed%
  Send, %str%
}

;...

^`::type(100, "67890")
```

It is also possible to use multiline hotkeys, but you need to delimit their end with `return`. This approach seems preferred by the documetation:

```
^`::
  SetKeyDelay, 100
  Send, 67890
return
```